# sequelize how to select child of childs in a single table?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following table in a postgresql database

```
id | name       |active| parentId
--------------------------------
1  | food       | true | null
2  | soft drink | true | 1
3  | canned food| true | 1
4  | sweet      | true | 1
5  | candy      | true | 4
6  | chocolate  | true | 4
7  | chemical   | true | null
```

As you can see they are connected with a parent-child relationship by their Ids

like: food -> sweet -> candy, chocolate

I want to write a query with sequelize which will return the parent and all associated children.

Let's say I choose `food`, the query should return all the rows where the `parentId` equals to the `id` 1, then return all the rows where `parentId` equals 2,3,4 (the food's children), then return all the rows where `parentId`
equals 5,6 (sweet's children) etc, as long as there are children.

Is it doable in a single where object?

```
db.ItemGroup.findAll({
  where: {
    // query
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use : **[sequelize-hierarchy.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-hierarchy)**

Here you have to define the model like this :

```
var folder = sequelize.define('folder', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    parentId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        hierarchy: true // <------- HERE
    }
});
```

And I think , this is what you are looking for :

```
folder
.findAll({ hierarchy: true }) // <------- HERE
.then(function(results) {
    // results = [
    //  { id: 1, parentId: null, name: 'a', children: [
    //      { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: 'ab', children: [
    //          { id: 3, parentId: 2, name: 'abc' }
    //      ] }
    //  ] }
    // ]
});
```

You can checkout the link , there are more examples to show the possible things you can do with this library.

> **NOTE : You can also do this without the plugin, but tit will be very
>   length way , this is more cleaner.**

Comment: Thanks, really nice solution!